# Beginner - Google Sheets Script Syntax Error at end of simple script

Tags: javascript, email, variables, google-apps-script

I've mashed together a couple of functions for Google Apps Script but I'm getting a syntax error at the end. I'm a beginner and I'm not sure why Google Sheets Script editor is giving me the syntax error on the very last line.

```
function CheckSales() {
  // Fetch the monthly sales
  var monthSalesRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Day Breakdown").getRange("K35"); 
  var monthSales = monthSalesRange.getValue();
  // Check totals sales
  if (monthSales > 999){
  function sendEmail() {
   var recipient = "myemail";
   var subject = "SubjectTest";
  var body = "Simple Message + monthSales variable tag here.";
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
 }
}
```

> Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input line: 13 file: unit_notifier.gs

I'm a beginnier so I didn't know what to do or where to turn.

- I tried deleting the trailing "}".
- Removing part of the script.

I would appreciate learning what I did wrong and any tips on resources for the future. I'm am incredibly grateful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try it this way:

```
function checkSales() {
  var monthSalesRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Day Breakdown").getRange("K35");
  var monthSales = monthSalesRange.getValue();
  if (monthSales > 999) {
    var recipient = "myemail";
    var subject = "SubjectTest";
    var body = "Simple Message " + monthSales;
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
  }
}
```

If you wish to create a standalone sendEmail function then you can but you need to have some parameters to pass recipient, subject and body and the call would simply be something like `sendEmail(recipient,subject,body);`

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be that the **sendEmail** function is defined but you never called it and the variable **monthSales** is not included in the body of the email. Try this possible approach.

```
function checkSales(){
  // Fetch the monthly sales
  var monthSalesRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Day Breakdown").getRange("K35");
  var monthSales = monthSalesRange.getValue();
  // Check totals sales
  if (monthSales > 999){
    sendEmail(monthSales);
  }
}

function sendEmail(monthSales) {
  var recipient = "myemail";
  var subject = "SubjectTest";
  var body = "Simple Message. Total sales for the month: " + monthSales;
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
}
```